# Permission callback to check if user has application password

Tags: php, rest-api

So I have the following registered rest route:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'instagram', '/posts/', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'instagram_posts',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_false'
    ]);
});
```

Which now gets this error when I run it in Postman:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

If I change `'permission_callback' => '__return_false'` to `'permission_callback' => '__return_true'` I get my array of objects via Postman.

---

I have a user called `Source` which has a generated Application password as shown here:

[image]

How do I properly format my rest route to check for the user application authentication?

I want to be able to provide the Application authenticated inside Postman so that I can properly get data back.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating roles/capabilities and application passwords. *This problem has nothing to do with application passwords.*

Users, not authentication methods have roles/capabilities. That includes application passwords. WP wants to know if *you* can do that, an application password is just a way of identifying you to WordPress.

Application passwords are a way of authenticating ***who***, that you are who you say you are. `permission_callback` isn't interested in that though, just because you are indeed verified as you, does not mean you have permission to do what you're trying to do.

For example, you could use an application password on a user with the subscriber role to create a post, but subscribers cannot create posts. It's like having a pass backstage, but it's not a VIP pass. Likewise you can't use different application passwords with different access levels, because it's the users access level that's being checked, not the authentication method.

So `__return_false` is telling it that you are not allowed to use that endpoint. Not because you are no longer logged in, or because you used an application password, but because you do not have the ability in this API. By using `__return_false`, nobody has permission to use this regardless of their role or how they accessed the REST API endpoint.

To make this work, you need to instead pass a function that returns true when Source is the user, or when a user of that role/capability uses the API. Much like only users who can edit posts are able to edit posts with the API. `__return_false` says that *nobody* is able to use this.

If you need to check if the current user who made the request has permission to do something, use `current_user_can`.

To be clear:

- users have roles and capabilities
- authentication methods are for identifying who you are, not what you can do

  - this includes application passwords and cookie based sessions
- you can't attach capabilities to an authentication method, you either are, or aren't logged in, that's it
- WordPress takes care of wether you are logged in, you're not meant to check for this yourself in the REST API or elsewhere, **`is_user_logged_in()` is all you need**
- WordPress, not you, not the REST API callback, is what checks the application password. REST API endpoints should not touch application passwords or handle authentication themselves.

Comment: Within my rest_route, what is the best way to indicate who can hit an endpoint on the route? I would set this up in Postman, but I was the user "Source" who has an application password, to be the only one that can make requests to that endpoint.

Comment: Would it involve things such as `is_user('source')` or is there a specific wordpress function that can check user application passwords?

Comment: `permission_callback` is basically asking the question _"can the currently logged in user do this?"_ You don't need special REST API specific know how to do this. E.g. if you want the check to be "if this user the user called Source" then you would do it the same way here as you would anywhere else in WordPress or in a theme template etc. **Importantly, application passwords are irrelevant here and have nothing to do with this. There is no connection between your problem and app passwords, it's pure coincidence**

Comment: The function you are looking for is `current_user_can()`